# How to do substitution within substituion in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

Example:

```
X=TEST
TEST_VAR=123

eval echo ${${X}_VAR}
```

This gives the error:

```
${${X}_VAR}: bad substitution
```

How can I achieve what I'm looking to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape the dollar sign:

```
eval echo \$${X}_VAR
```

Answer (score 2):

Or avoid `eval` altogether with a `nameref` (created with `declare -n`), e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

X=TEST
TEST_VAR=123

declare -n foo=${X}_VAR

echo $foo
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./myscript
123
```